# Proportional Editing Circle of Influence not working with mouse wheel

Tags: edit-mode

I am using Blender 3.3 and I cannot get the circle of influence to fluctuate with my mouse wheel or Page Up / Down keys. All I am trying to do is widen a ring band at the top proportionately. I have done this a few times before without issue, but now if I use the wheel it just zooms my item in / out. In addition, if I remember correctly, I just had to highlight one of the vertices around the band, scale it out and it widened the top proportionately. I have searched the web and cannot find anything.

Comment: I think it's possible that the circle is simply "too big", so large that it is both offscreen, and influencing your entire mesh at once (in what appears to be "zooming in"). Try scrolling the mouse wheel "up" for what seems like way too much and see if the circle shrinks back to where you can see it on screen.

Comment: In order to not simply scroll and hope the circle comes back to visibility, you can check its size: as soon as you have _Proportional Editing_ turned on and activate a tool like moving, rotating or scaling, in the top left of your viewport you can see the tool values like how far you are moving, and with _Proportional Editing_ enabled the first should read "Proportional Size (Smooth):" and then a value in meters. This can give you a hint how far you have to scroll in which direction (the word "Smooth" can be replaced by something else, depending on the selected proportional falloff).